# How to fix Runtime Error 91 in Excel VBA script

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a little script that takes some data from a website table and fills it into cells in Excel. I need this in order to make searching through that data and filtering it easier for myself. However I have ran into a little problem, every time I run my script it does what it's supposed to do for around 9 to 11 pages (about 250 cell entries) and then stops with an error message popping up saying "Runtime Error 91" Object variable or With block variable not set. It never runs all the way through till the end and I only get a small fraction of the data that I was supposed to get.

I am not an expert in programming and even less of an expert in VBA, so if I'm doing something wrong please let me know. I've been stuck on this problem for a few days. I do not know what to do to fix this problem. I've looked for fixes on Google, YouTube and even Microsoft's own website, but can't figure out why this error is popping up in my own script.

I know that this problem is encountered when; 1) you attempt to use an object variable that isn't yet referencing a valid object or when 2) you attempt to use an object variable that has been set to Nothing. But I can't figure in which part of my code I am making that mistake. Help much appreciated.

---

UPDATE:
When I start the page number from say 8 and it goes up to say 15 it has no problem pulling that data from the site, so I don't think it has anything to do with the specific page numbers (I could be wrong about this). But when I set the page number to 17 instead of 15 the error message pops up almost immediately. So, could it be the range between pages that's causing this?

UPDATE 2:
It's also kind of inconsistent when the error message pops up, when I run the script again with the same page numbers (8 to 17) it runs through the entire thing with no hiccups. (Weird) Then I change the page numbers from (8 to 18) and it gets through 2 pages and stops.

UPDATE 3:
Is it possible that this is happening because I am being rate limited?

```
Sub GrabInfo()

    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer

    Dim r As Integer
    Dim p As Integer
    Dim c As Integer

    r = 0
    p = 0
    c = 0

    Dim sDD1 As String
    Dim sDD2 As String
    Dim sDD3 As String

    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    'objIE.Visible = True

    Do While p < 53
    p = p + 1

        'Setting row to zero after the new page loads but before the data gets pulled
        r = 0

        objIE.navigate "URLGOESHERE.com/123456789?pageNum=" & p
        Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

        Do While r < 25
        'Increment the row (gets reset after each page)
        r = r + 1
        'Increment the cell (never gets reset)
        c = c + 1

            'Pulling data from site row by row and setting each child to temp sDD strings
            sDD1 = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("table-content")(r - 1).Children(0).innerText
            sDD2 = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("table-content")(r - 1).Children(2).innerText
            sDD3 = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("table-content")(r - 1).Children(3).innerText

            Debug.Print sDD1 & " | " & sDD2 & " | " & sDD3 & " - " & _
            "Cell # = " & c & " ROW # = " & r & " PAGE # = " & p

            'Filling in the temp sDD strings into excel cells
            Range("A" & (c + 1)).Value = sDD1
            Range("B" & (c + 1)).Value = sDD2
            Range("C" & (c + 1)).Value = sDD3

        Loop
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Good to know.

Comment: Wondering if the class is changing which causes the issue

Comment: Yea, I don't know. As far as I can see, sDD1, sDD2 and sDD3 stay as Strings. And p, r and c stay as Integers. My only suspicion is objIE is somehow changing class, but I don't see where.

Comment: You need to narrow down the issue using the debugger. First, try to isolate it to a specific page using an `if p = somevalue then Debug.Print("something")`, and set a breakpoint on the print statement. Start with a high value for `p`, run the code, and see if you hit the breakpoint. If not, reduce the value and run again to see if you get to the break. Repeat as needed until you see if it's a specific page. Once you've figured that out, add the same sort of `if` in the inner loop, checking for `p = thepage and c = somevalue`. That should narrow it down to something you can then step through.

Comment: (continued) You have several possibilities: GetElementsByClassName could fail, Children() could as well. Range() wiith an invalid value for c could be an issue. Isolating the problem is the first step to solving it.

Comment: I'm not an expert either, but you are missing one of the `Loop` statements.

Comment: An addition to @Ken White's suggestion: insert `Debug.Assert objIE Is Not Nothing` before each line you reference `objIE`. This will stop the app running whenever the object gets `Nothing`.

Comment: @AcsErno I tried it and it didn't work. Error message pops up saying "Compile error" Invalid Use of Object.

Comment: Sorry, use this: `Debug.Assert Not (objIE Is Nothing)

Comment: Spread your Debug prints over several lines so that you can know exactly where it fails and the last values obtained. It can give you an hint.